# Can't get UIImageView objects to animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have set up a .h, .m page to animate some UIImageView objects, but can't get them to animate. Have not been getting any warnings, errors.

Can you tell me what's wrong? TIA

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *predictionLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *predictionArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

- (void) makePrediction;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize predictionArray;
@synthesize imageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_s4.png"];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    [self.view insertSubview:self.imageView atIndex:0];
    self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00001.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00002.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00003.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00004.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00005.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00006.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00007.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00008.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00009.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00010.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00011.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00012.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00013.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00014.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00015.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00016.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00017.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00018.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00019.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00020.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00021.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00022.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00023.png"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"cball00024.png"], nil];
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

    self.predictionArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"It is certain",
                                @"All signs are YES",
                                @"The stars are not aligned",
                                @"My reply is no",
                                @"It is doubtful",
                                @"Better not tell you now",
                                @"Concentrate and ask again",
                                @"Unable to answer now", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) makePrediction
{
    NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.predictionArray.count);
    self.predictionLabel.text = [self.predictionArray objectAtIndex:index];

    [self.imageView startAnimating];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void) motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   self.predictionLabel.text = @"";
}

- (void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if  (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
        [self makePrediction];
    }
}

- (void) motionCancelled:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"motion cancelled");
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.predictionLabel.text = @"";
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [self makePrediction];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure - (void) makePrediction is to be called while you run your code?

Comment: try start animation just after setting animation images and check whether its working or not??

Comment: Yes, that's to call the predictionArray which holds the random quotes.

Comment: "try start animation just after setting animation images and check whether its working or not?? " Sorry, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I create a new "Single View" project, paste your code in the view controller and add a few test images, your code works fine for me as it is (Xcode 5, iOs7, on simulator). The problem you are experiencing must depend on how you set up the views or the project.

A few suggestions:

- Check that the animation is actually being called (log  makePrediction()), maybe you have some other object in your storyboard that can act as First Responder.
- Check that you have all the images imported in your project.
- Try to initialise the image view with one of the animation frames, NOT with the background, or have two different imageViews, one for the animation and the other for the background.

Comment: Hi, just found out the problem. I had it set up as an ImageView and Image in IB, and also programmatically at the same time. So I went into IB and deleted the ImageView and Image. Then when I compiled it, it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, it had to be a setup problem, there was nothing explicitly wrong with the code itself.